# Empty response when using curl for JSON

Tags: json, curl

This is potentially very basic, but I'm trying to access the JSON under this URL: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static.

You can see data if you visit the page in a browser but when I use

```
curl https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static
```

I get a 200 response but no data (at least that I can see).

Is there something I'm missing? Possibly header related?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was indeed header related. I needed a "User-Agent"

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Testing" https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static
```

worked fine.

In my searching I also discovered you if you go into the network tab of Chrome developer options you can right click the request and copy the curl. Hope this helps someone.